# Does Collections.synchronized map makes Iterator threadsafe

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator, synchronized, concurrentmodification

There are two threads in a system. One is a reader thread and another is a writer thread.

The map is synchronized using the following code.

```
Map<String,ArrayList<String>> m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>())
```

The reader thread obtains an Iterator on the values of the map and at the same time writer thread modifies the map.

So, my question is will the Iterator throw `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Comment: How can anything modify the map? You have not kept a reference to it.

Comment: Well, I am about to design a system. I was thinking of using ReadWriteLock. That's why I wanted to explore all possible scenarios.

Comment: The code in your question is 100% threadsafe because it is not possible to modify the map - there is no direct reference to the map.

Comment: @Bohemian, a synchronized view is not immutable. The underlying map can be modified simply by calling `m.put(String, List);`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe. It's not safe to do so. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29) says

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned map when iterating over any of its collection views

`Collections.synchronized...` makes single method calls atomic so they don't need further synchronization. But iteration is more than a single method call so it needs extra synchronization. Below is an example

```
    Map<String, String> shared = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());

    new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (shared) {
                for (String key : shared.keySet()) {
                    System.out.println(key);
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            try {
                // this is atomic
                shared.put(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "Yo!");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: So, I guess I need to use synchronization for both reading and writing right?

Comment: @Touchstone depends on what you do during writing. Single method calls no, if more than one needs to be atomic yes, see edit in answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes,the `Iterator` may still throw `ConcurrentModificationException` as it is not related with synchronization(although its name suggests so).The `Iterator` tries to detect structural modifications(addition or deletion of Objects) in a best effort attempt and is irrespective of whether the operations of a List are synchronized or not.
Once an Iterator has been obtained through `List.iterator() or List.listIterator()`,any changes done to the List (apart by the Iterator itself) will throw a CME exception in best effort basis.
The only way you can ensure that `ConcurrentModificationException` is not thrown 
is either by having your Reader operations complete first and then writer operations(or vice-versa) or by using a fail-safe Iterator from `ConcurrentHashMap`

```
Map hashmap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>();
----

Map<String,ArrayList<String>> m = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,ArrayList<String>(hashmap));
```

ConcurrentHashMap is a fail-safe iterator and now you can focus on synchronizing reader-writer operations than worrying about ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: So, I guess I need to use synchronisation for both reading and writing right?

Comment: Only synchronization wont be sufficient,you need to ensure that operations of iterators dont interleave on one another.Alternatively I suggest you use a fail-safe iterator from ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: But fail-safe iterator uses the deep-copy, that will result in dirty read!!

Comment: @Touchstone Then I suggest you should synchronize your Iteration operations right from obtaining it Map.values().iterator() to using that iterator

Comment: Note that the question needs clarification - The code in the question makes modification impossible because no reference is held to it.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was thinking about. But the problem is if I have more than one readers then synchronization will make the systems sequential i.e. single threaded. Because if I use synchronization on read operation then only one thread will read at a time. Should I go for ReadWriteLock?

Comment: @Touchstone Why will yo utry to iterate everytime after a single reader or writer operation.Could you put some more code as to what you are trying to acheive?